# with css3, is is possible to have left/right padding in a span iff not empty

Tags: html, css

have span that may or may not have text content.

is there a way to have left and right padding if and only if there is text content?

was thinking of using pseudo classes :first and :last, seeing how some css3 examples make the first character extra large for example.

will this work or is it a pipe dream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `:empty` pseudo-selector that will do what you need.

```
span {
  padding:0 20px;
}

span:empty {
  padding:0;
}
```

More here - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo

Comment: I was making life too complicated

Answer (score 3):

You can with css's :empty pseudo-class, but as you may have guessed, it works in everything except IE. But apparently IE 9 beta does support it.

documentation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo

browser support:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t32

Answer (score 1):

There is a css :empty pseudo tag, but it can be unreliable in IE (suprise...).

See here for details: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aempty)

If your text was in its own container (a `<p>` tag for example), you could just target that instead, and apply the padding to that.

Comment: you guys are good - thanks - are you part of the mozilla team?

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with mozilla, but id bookmark their site, its really useful.